# Why am I only getting one match?

Tags: perl

I am parsing a log file trying to pull out the lines where the phrase "failures=" is a unique non-zero digit.

The first part of my perl one liner will pull out all the lines where "failures" are greater than zero.  But that part of the log file repeats until a new failure occurs, i.e., after the first failure the log entries will be "failures=1" until the second error then it will read, "failures=2".

What I'd like to do is pull only the first line where that value changes and I thought I had it with this:

```
cat -n Logstats.out | perl -nle 'print "Line No. $1: failures=$2; eventDelta=$3; tracking_id=$4" if /\s(\d+)\t.*failures=(\d+).*eventDelta=(.\d+).*tracking_id="(\d+)"/ && $2 > 0' | perl -ne 'print unless $a{/failures=\d+/}++'
```

However, that only pulls the first non-zero "failure" line and nothing else.  What do I need to change for it to pull all the unique values for "failures"?

thanks in advance!

Update: The amount of text in each line up to the "tracking_id" is more text than I can post.  Sorry!

> 2011-09-06 14:14:18 [INFO] [logStats]: name=somename id=d6e6f4f0-4c0d-93b6-7a71-8e3100000030 
>    successes=1 failures=0 skipped=0 eventDelta=41 original=188 simulated=229 
>    totalDelta=41 averageDelta=41 min=0 max=41 averageOriginalDuration=188 averageSimulatedDuriation=229(txid = b3036eca-6288-48ef-166f-5ae200000646 
>    date = 2011-09-02 08:00:00 type = XML xml 
>    =

Comment: Can you show some sample input, and what you want as output?

Comment: The input is proprietary and so I can't post it, but the output is something like this: Line No. 76: failures=1; eventDelta=-59; tracking_id=137609515.  That's the result of running the above code.

Comment: "there's nothing past what I'm posting that I'm interested in" -- Really? Not even 'tracking_id'?

Comment: I don't see anything in your data that fits this pattern: a space, followed by digits, followed by a tab (or space for that matter, since tabs aren't preserved).

Comment: the "cat -n" adds white space, a line number, and then a tab before the actual output of the log file.

Comment: You don't need that. `print "Line=$.; ..."` does the same.

Comment: Note that `!$seen{$_}++` won't find unique failure counts. It will return results with no duplicate failure counts. That could very well be what you want, but that's not what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'print unless $a{/failures=\d+/}++'
```

does not work because a hash subscript is evaluated in scalar context, and the [`m//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) operator does not return the match in scalar context.  Instead, it returns 1.  So (since every line matches), what you wrote is equivalent to:

```
perl -ne 'print unless $a{1}++'
```

and I think you can see the problem there.

There's a number of ways to work around that, but I'd use:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /(failures=\d+)/ and $a{$1}++'
```

However, I'd do the whole thing in one call to `perl`, including numbering the lines:

```
perl -nle '
   print "Line No. $.: failures=$1; eventDelta=$2; tracking_id=$3"
      if /failures=(\d+).*?eventDelta=(.\d+).*?tracking_id="(\d+)"/
      && $1 > 0
      && !$seen{$1}++
' Logstats.out
```

([`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_LINE_NUMBER) automatically counts input lines in Perl. The line breaks can be removed if desired, but it will actually work as is.)

Comment: Perfect, I tried that and it worked exactly like I wanted it too.  Thanks again.

Comment: @cjm, I added line breaks to make the code readable. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a hash to store te results and print it:

```
perl -nle '$f{$2} ||= "Line No. $1: failures=$2; eventDelta=$3; tracking_id=$4" if /\s(\d+)\t.*failures=(\d+).*eventDelta=(.\d+     ).*tracking_id="(\d+)"/ && $2;END{ print $f{$_} for keys %f }' Logstats.out
```

(not tested due to missing input data...)

HTH,
Paul

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's what I was trying to do with:  perl -ne 'print unless $a{/failures=\d+/}++'.  But let me give your idea a try.  I'll also see if I can remove any sensitive data from the input so that I can post it.

Comment: Ah yes, the “Orkish Manuever”; that is, the OR-cache.

Answer (score 1):

Since your input does not match your regex, I can't really help you. But I can tell you that this is doing a *lot* of backtracking--and that's bad if there is a lot of data after the part that you're interested in.

So here is some alternative ideas:

```
qr{ \s                    # a single space
    failures=(\d+)        # the entry for failures
    \s+                   # at least one space
    skipped=\d+           # skipped 
    \s+ 
    eventDelta=(.\d+)     
    .*?                   # any number of non-newline characters *UNTIL* ...
    \btracking_id="(\d+)" # another specified sequence of data
  }x;
```

- The parser will scan "skipped=" and then a group of digits a lot faster than scanning the rest of the line and backtracking when it fails back to 'eventDelta=', it is better to put it in, if you *know* it will always be there.
- Since you don't put `tracking_id` in your example, I can't tell how it occurs, so in this case we used a *non-greedy* any match which will always be looking for the next sequence. Again, if there is a lot of data in the line, then you do not want to scan to then end and backtrack until you find that you've already read 'tracking_id="nnn"'. However, lookaheads cost processing time, it is still better to spell out 'skipped=' and all possible values then a non-greedy "any match".
- You'll also notice that after accepting any data, I specify that tracking_id should appear at a word boundary, which disambiguates it from the possible--though not likely 'backtracking_id='.